# PHP Can't Open Network File

Tags: php, iis, fopen

I have a site using PHP scripts running on Windows Server 2012 R2 in IIS. I am trying to use fopen to read a file on another server in our network but am having problems. I am able to use the fopen command to open files on the local server and using the PHP CLI, I can successfully open the file on the remote server.

However, when I try to process it via the site using my browser, it fails with the error:

> "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

In IIS, I created a new Application Pool and set its identity as a Domain Administrator which has admin access to both servers but this didn't seem to help. This is the same account that I ran the CLI with when it worked.

Here is my PHP script code that I'm using:

```
fopen("//remoteservername/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/test.html", "w") or die("Can't open file!");
```

I've tried using backslashes (with escaping ones too). I've tried using FILE:// ahead of the path. I've tried mapping the remote server's drive to the web server running PHP and using a path like Y:\inetpub...I've tried using "rb" instead of "w" since they're both Windows servers.

I feel like it has to do with the account/identity that the site is running under but I'm not sure why it still wouldn't be working after I changed it.

UPDATE: I mentioned that fopen works reading files on the local server but it seems that's only true if I use a relative path like below...

```
fopen("test.html", "w") or die("Can't open file!");
```

If I try opening that same file on the local server using an absolute path like shown below, it fails. So I'm not convinced anymore that it's an identity issue...

```
fopen("//localservername/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/test.html", "w") or die("Can't open file!");
```

UPDATE: So I ran shell_exec("whoami") at both the CLI and via browser. When I do it in the CLI, it shows my domain account that I'm running the shell at. However, when I run the script via browser, it shows "nt authority\iusr". Any ideas how to get that to run under a different user? Changing the Application Pool Identity within IIS does not seem to make a difference from what I can tell on my tests.

```
echo shell_exec("whoami");
```

Comment: If its any help, a long time ago I did battle with PHP/IIS and networked drives. The admin/developer of the site was seeing inconsistent behaviour reported by different users. This was an intranet application using NTLM for authentication. The only rational explanation we could come up to explain the behaviour was that the PHP code was running with the permissions supplied via NTLM (erk!). We never fully validated this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved. I had to go into IIS > *FastCGI Settings* > Select my PHP app > Click *Edit* on right sidebar > Expand *Advanced* menu > Change *Protocol* from *NamedPipe* to *Tcp*.

The way I came across this was I did a test on another Windows Server we have running PHP and it was using the correct account/identity that was set in the AppPool. So I setup a new site on my server to test with and I couldn't even run `echo shell_exec("whoami");` When I began troubleshooting that, I came across this site: http://tech.trailmax.info/2012/12/php-warning-shell_exec-unable-to-execute-on-iis-7/

I followed those steps and not only did that fix my problem not being able to run `shell_exec` but also started running my PHP scripts using the domain account I had set in the IIS AppPool. Now `fopen` works as expected.

Comment: Wow, I think this just helped me big-time.   I've been struggling for several days with a web app that acts as a file manager on a UNC share.  If I had IIS Anonymous access on, it worked perfectly, but I needed to somehow snag the user's network username (just to record who did what, really).  So, I turned off Anonymous but left Windows Authentication enabled.  And fopen would fail when trying to create a new file on the UNC share.  But performing this little trick seems to have fixed that.  Thank you !!

Comment: I wish I could give you more up-votes man. You really helped me big time I've been struggling this issue for days. Thank you!

Comment: Holimoli! You just helped me so much, I wish I could upvote a thousand times! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

As the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php) says you should use \\localservername\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\test.html

But as the \ it's a reserved character for escape other special characters you should double the number of \ like this:

```
fopen("\\\\localservername\\c$\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\test.html", "w") or die("Can't open file!");
```

If it doesn't work **you should check if the user of the webserver which it's running the php script has the needed permissions** to access that resource.

The administrative shares (drive + $) usually are only allowed to administrators.

IMHO it should be better to create a shared folder with the permissions of the webserver user instead of using the administrative share (c$)

Comment: I mentioned trying backslashes in my original post including extra ones like your example. I checked the current user using both whoami and get_current_user() and it shows it's running under "NT Authority\IUSR" even though I have my IIS site using an App Pool with a domain account as its identity. I think this is the problem but not sure how to fix it. I tried giving IUSR full access to the test.html file but it made no change. And I know that I'm using an administrative share but have also tested creating a share on the server like you suggested but still no change. Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: Here's what the PHP error log shows. The first example is trying to access using the C$ administrative share. The second example is using a shared folder named "test" that I created and assigned permissions to.

[28-Dec-2016 08:14:00 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  fopen(\\localservername\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\test.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 100

[28-Dec-2016 08:15:09 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  fopen(\\localservername\test\test.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 100

Comment: Obviously it's a problem with the permissions. Did you tried to add full permissions to "All" users on the share only for testing? Also I think NT Authority\IUSR it's a local user which only works in the IIS machine. It's not a domain user, so it won't have permissions on the other machine.You should edit the pool and use a non-local account, to which you will add permission on the second machine.

Comment: Check my other msg I already fixed it. The protocol wasn't properly set in the FastCgi settings which wasn't letting it run under the domain account. Changing that setting allowed it to run the scripts using the domain account and all is working now.

Comment: Nice! Mark it as answer for your question. Regards,