# PHP/Windows Server/IIS Accessing file via PHP through symbolic link to folder on another server

Tags: php, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Good day! I have hit a wall.

I'm trying to get PHP to load a file from a folder on another server and have tried so many methods and variations of permissions (IIS/PHP use Windows Authentication) but have yet to find a solution. I am so close I can taste it.

The files are in a folder on the other server e.g. `\\otherServer\my_photos`

In order to access them this I have created a symbolic link on the server hosting the PHP site, e.g.

```
C:\my_photos > \\otherServer\my_photos
```

I am then doing various tests to determine whether or not the page has access, e.g:

```
$path = 'C:\\my_photos'; 
$isReadable = is_readable($path);
var_dump($isReadable);
```

The above returns `TRUE`.

However, if I do this:

```
$path = 'C:\\my_photos\photo_1.jpg'; 
$isReadable = is_readable($path);
var_dump($isReadable);
```

It returns `FALSE`.

The permissions on the file `photo_1.jpg` are identical to the folder `my_photos` so I suspect the cause is something else, such as some sort of security restricting affecting access to files on other servers, but I am out of ideas. I will reward any assistance with virtual gratitude and am even willing to draw you a picture with a personal message.

**UPDATE:**
If we switch Windows Authentication off and Anonymous Authentication on (running under the ApplicationPoolIdentity) it works, which seems to suggest that a) it's not some confusing cross-server security issue and b) the problem may relate more to the way PHP/fastCGI impersonates Windows users. Will switch back to Windows auth and keep testing!

Comment: Can you open the image from command prompt or image viewer?  Solve this first if not.

Comment: Can't you have a webserver on the other server? Life is much easier when there's just HTTP involved

Comment: Why not map \\otherServer\my_photos to a drive letter on the server? Probably better than symlinks. But also you need to have correct permissions on all the files, not just the folder itself. They aren't necessarily the same. Permission generally should be given to the account that the application is running under, not the account of the user accessing the resource, unless you're attempting to use some sort of pass-through authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working (after three days of head-scratching) by changing the FastCGI 'protocol' from `NamedPipe` to `TCP`, as detailed in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367358/1358231

I'm still not entirely sure why this works but will keep looking. In the end there was no need for a symbolic link (or mapped drive) - we could access the remote file directly via the UNC path.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the slash preceding the directory name. It should look like this.

```
$path = 'C:\\my_photos\\photo_1.jpg'; 
$isReadable = is_readable($path);
var_dump($isReadable);
```

Every slash gets escaped, so, \otherServer\my_photos would become:

```
$path = '\\\\otherServer\\my_photos';
```

Note the **four** slashes before the server name, and the **two** slashes before the directory name.